# Function involving AJAX not returning value - jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a document.ready function like this;

```
  function myfun(){
    var xx;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'handler.php',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
          xx = result;
        },
    });
    return xx;
  }


  var a;
  a = myfun();
  alert(a);
```

`handle.php` is set to echo `1234`. But I am getting alert as "undefined". How can I fix this? Expected alert is "1234" (the reply from ajax handler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's asynchronous. Use a callback:

```
function myfun(){

    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'handler.php',
        cache: false
    });
}

myfun().done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Or if you're using an old jQuery version without deferred objects:

```
function myfun(done){

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'handler.php',
        cache: false,
        success: done
    });
}

myfun(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ajax+not+returning+data

Comment: alright... problem is fixed.. I will mark this as accepted soon...

Answer (score 0):

Because you return the value before the ajax call can complete, ajax call are by default async, you can `alert` inside the `success` callback, at that point your variable will have the value you set:

```
function myfun(){
  var xx;
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'handler.php',
      cache: false,
      success: function(result) {
        xx = result;
        alert(xx);
      },
  });
}

myfun();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem of asynchronous calls. You can rewrite code such as:

```
var xx;
  var a;

  function myfun(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'handler.php',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
          xx = result;
        },
    });
  }

 myfun();
 alert(xx);
```